# Is there a record for threefold repetition for when the claimed positions are the farthest apart, in terms of moves?

Tags: draw, threefold-repetition, records

That’s one long question, so let’s break it down. Threefold repetition, as many know, is when a draw occurs, after the same position, with all piece types on the same square, all possible moves and rights are the same, happens three times in a game of chess. The draw can be claimed whether or not the positions are consecutive or not.

My question is based on the non-consecutive part. Is there any sort of or record for when a draw was claimed for threefold repetition, when the three congruent positions, are the farthest apart by number of moves?

Essentially, the “number of moves” means this: Somtime in the game, position one occurs. So and so many moves later, position two happens. Then the third and final position is reached at last.

One could view this in two ways: What is the greatest number of moves between positions one and three, OR,  What is the greatest number of moves from position one to position two, and then from position two to position three?

The game must have ended on the basis of a threefold-repetition claim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an improvement over my original suggestion. The game finishes after White's 128th move, repeating the position after their 62nd and 87th moves, so the distance is 66 moves. The source for this game was Mark Crowther's [The Week in Chess](http://theweekinchess.com/).

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Int ch-Central SRB Op A"]
[Site "Paracin SRB"]
[Date "2016.07.12"]
[Round "7.38"]
[White "Tisma,I"]
[Black "Krasteva,Beloslava"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]

1. Nf3 d5 2. d4 Nf6 3. c4 e6 4. g3 Be7 5. Bg2 O-O 6. O-O Nbd7 7. Qc2 c5 8.
cxd5 exd5 9. dxc5 Nxc5 10. Nc3 Be6 11. Be3 Rc8 12. Rfd1 Nce4 13. Qa4 Nxc3
14. bxc3 a6 15. Rab1 Bd7 16. Qb3 b5 17. Ne5 Be6 18. Bd4 Qc7 19. a4 Rb8 20.
axb5 Rxb5 21. Qa2 Rfb8 22. Rxb5 axb5 23. Nd3 Ne4 24. Qb2 Bf6 25. Bxe4 dxe4
26. Nb4 Rd8 27. Nc2 Bc4 28. Ne3 Bg5 29. Ng2 Ra8 30. Ra1 Qb7 31. h4 Be7 32.
Rxa8+ Qxa8 33. Ne3 Qa4 34. Qd2 Be6 35. Kh2 h6 36. Ng2 Qa8 37. Qf4 Bc4 38.
Qg4 Bf8 39. Nf4 Qc6 40. h5 Be6 41. Nxe6 Qxe6 42. Qxe6 fxe6 43. Be5 Kf7 44.
Kh3 Bc5 45. e3 Be7 46. Kg4 Bg5 47. Bd4 Kf8 48. f4 Bf6 49. Bxf6 gxf6 50. f5
e5 51. Kh3 Ke7 52. Kg2 Kd6 53. Kf2 Kc5 54. Ke2 b4 55. g4 bxc3 56. Kd1 Kd6
57. Kc2 Kc6 58. Kxc3 Kc5 59. Kb3 Kd5 60. Kb4 Kd6 61. Kb5 Kd5 62. Ka4 Kc6
63. Kb3 Kd7 64. Kc3 Kc7 65. Kb4 Kd6 66. Kb5 Kd5 67. Kb6 Kd6 68. Kb7 Kd7 69.
Ka6 Kc6 70. Ka5 Kc5 71. Ka4 Kc6 72. Kb3 Kd7 73. Kc3 Kc7 74. Kc4 Kc6 75. Kb3
Kd7 76. Kb4 Kd6 77. Kb5 Kd5 78. Ka6 Kc6 79. Ka7 Kc7 80. Ka8 Kc8 81. Ka7 Kc7
82. Ka6 Kc6 83. Ka5 Kc5 84. Ka4 Kc6 85. Ka3 Kc5 86. Kb3 Kd5 87. Ka4 Kc6 88.
Kb4 Kd6 89. Kb5 Kd5 90. Kb6 Kd6 91. Ka5 Kc5 92. Ka4 Kc6 93. Ka3 Kc7 94. Kb3
Kd7 95. Kb4 Kd6 96. Kb5 Kd5 97. Kb6 Kd6 98. Ka5 Kc5 99. Ka4 Kc6 100. Ka3
Kc7 101. Kb2 Kd8 102. Kc3 Kc7 103. Kb3 Kd7 104. Kc3 Kc7 105. Kb4 Kd6 106.
Ka5 Kc5 107. Ka4 Kc6 108. Kb3 Kd7 109. Kc3 Kc7 110. Kb4 Kd6 111. Kb5 Kd7
112. Kb6 Kd6 113. Kb7 Kd7 114. Ka6 Kc6 115. Ka5 Kc5 116. Ka4 Kc6 117. Ka3
Kc7 118. Kb3 Kd7 119. Kc3 Kc7 120. Kb3 Kd7 121. Ka4 Kc6 122. Kb4 Kd6 123.
Kb5 Kd5 124. Kb6 Kd6 125. Kb5 Kd5 126. Kb6 Kd6 127. Kb5 Kd5 128. Ka4
1/2-1/2
```

The following was my original offering which finishes after Black's 146th move, with the same position having previously occurred after their 96th and 117th moves.

```
[fen ""]
[Event "Internet Section 14-A"]
[Site "Dos Hermanas"]
[Date "2003.03.14"]
[Round "1"]
[White "Keskinen, Sauli"]
[Black "Verhagen, Emmanuel"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 exd4 4. c3 d3 5. Bxd3 d6 6. h3 Be7 7. O-O Nf6 8.
Nd4 O-O 9. Nd2 Bd7 10. f4 Qc8 11. N2f3 a6 12. Be3 Nxd4 13. cxd4 c5 14. Rc1
b5 15. b3 Qb7 16. dxc5 dxc5 17. Bxc5 Bxc5+ 18. Rxc5 Qb6 19. b4 a5 20. a3
axb4 21. axb4 Rfd8 22. Kh2 Be6 23. Qb1 h6 24. Rxb5 Qd6 25. Ne5 Nd7 26. Rd1
Nxe5 27. fxe5 Qe7 28. Rc5 Qg5 29. Qc1 Qg6 30. b5 Ra2 31. Bf1 Rxd1 32. Qxd1
Qxe4 33. Qd8+ Kh7 34. Bd3 Rxg2+ 35. Kh1 Bf5 36. Bxe4 Bxe4 37. Qd4 Rg4+ 38.
Kh2 Rg2+ 39. Kh1 Rg4+ 40. Kh2 Rg2+ 41. Kh1 Rg4+ 42. Qxe4+ Rxe4 43. Kg2 Rb4
44. Kg3 Kg6 45. Rd5 Kf5 46. Rd7 Kxe5 47. Rxf7 g5 48. Rh7 Rxb5 49. Rxh6 Kf5
50. Rh8 Rb3+ 51. Kh2 Kf4 52. Rf8+ Ke4 53. Kg2 Ke5 54. Rf2 Ke4 55. Rf8 Ke5
56. Re8+ Kf5 57. Rf8+ Kg6 58. Rg8+ Kh5 59. Rh8+ Kg6 60. Rf8 Kh5 61. Rf7 Kg6
62. Rf8 Kh5 63. Rc8 Kg6 64. Rc6+ Kh5 65. Rf6 g4 66. Rf5+ Kh4 67. hxg4 Kxg4
68. Rf8 Rb2+ 69. Kf1 Kg3 70. Ke1 Kg4 71. Rg8+ Kf3 72. Rf8+ Ke3 73. Re8+ Kf3
74. Rf8+ Ke3 75. Re8+ Kf3 76. Kd1 Rh2 77. Kc1 Rg2 78. Kd1 Rh2 79. Rf8+ Ke3
80. Re8+ Kd3 81. Rd8+ Ke3 82. Ra8 Kd3 83. Ra3+ Ke4 84. Ke1 Kf4 85. Kf1 Ke4
86. Kg1 Rb2 87. Ra4+ Kf3 88. Ra3+ Kf4 89. Ra8 Kf3 90. Rf8+ Kg3 91. Rg8+ Kf3
92. Rf8+ Kg3 93. Rg8+ Kf3 94. Ra8 Kg3 95. Ra3+ Kf4 96. Kf1 Ke4 97. Ke1 Kf4
98. Kd1 Rh2 99. Kc1 Ke4 100. Kb1 Kd4 101. Ra4+ Ke3 102. Ra8 Kd3 103. Rd8+
Kc3 104. Rd1 Kb3 105. Rd3+ Kc4 106. Rd8 Kc3 107. Rc8+ Kb3 108. Rb8+ Kc3
109. Rg8 Kb3 110. Rg3+ Kc4 111. Rg4+ Kb3 112. Rg3+ Kc4 113. Kc1 Kd4 114.
Kd1 Ke4 115. Ke1 Kf4 116. Ra3 Ke4 117. Kf1 Rb2 118. Ke1 Kd4 119. Ra4+ Ke3
120. Ra3+ Ke4 121. Kd1 Kd4 122. Kc1 Rh2 123. Ra8 Kc3 124. Rc8+ Kd3 125.
Rd8+ Ke3 126. Ra8 Kd3 127. Ra3+ Kc4 128. Ra4+ Kc3 129. Ra3+ Kc4 130. Ra8
Kc3 131. Rc8+ Kd3 132. Rd8+ Kc3 133. Rc8+ Kd3 134. Rd8+ Kc3 135. Rc8+ Kd3
136. Kb1 Kd4 137. Rd8+ Kc3 138. Rg8 Kb3 139. Rg3+ Kc4 140. Kc1 Kd4 141. Kd1
Ke4 142. Ke1 Kf4 143. Ra3 Ke4 144. Ra4+ Ke3 145. Ra3+ Ke4 146. Kf1 Rb2
1/2-1/2
```

I have some longer examples but, in those cases, the repetitions occur more than three times.

The original process was fairly messy but I have now streamlined it in the light of experience:

- Use my [pgn-extract](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/~djb/pgn-extract/) program to identify games with three-fold repetition.
- Use pgn-extract again to output the matched games in EPD notation - essentially, the FEN string after every move.
- Use a Perl script to read the EPD version of a game and find the distance between the first and last occurrences of the terminating position, and the number of repetitions.
- Sort the distances, find the largest and then match it up with the original game. As a side effect, this process allows those games that didn't actually end by repetition to be eliminated.

Of 3.2M games in one database, about 50,000 had 3-fold repetitions occurring somewhere but only around 35,000 ended by repetition. Of those, about 87% ended as soon as the third repetition occurred.

Here is an example with a longer distance: 73 moves occurring 10 times (48, 53, 61, etc.).

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "GER-chT U12"]
[Site "Verden/Aller"]
[Date "2002.12.30"]
[Round "7.2"]
[White "Mader, Manuela"]
[Black "Voelz, Michael"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. b4 Bxb4 5. c3 Be7 6. d4 exd4 7. O-O d3 8.
Qb3 d5 9. Bxd5 Na5 10. Bxf7+ Kf8 11. Qd5 Qxd5 12. Bxd5 c6 13. Bxg8 Rxg8 14.
Nbd2 c5 15. Nb3 Nc6 16. Ba3 c4 17. Bxe7+ Kxe7 18. Nbd4 Nxd4 19. Nxd4 Bd7
20. a4 b6 21. Rfb1 Rgb8 22. Rb4 Rc8 23. Kf1 Kd6 24. Ke1 Rc5 25. Kd2 Rf8 26.
Ke3 Ke5 27. a5 b5 28. Rab1 a6 29. Rf1 g5 30. Nf3+ Ke6 31. Nd4+ Ke5 32. Nf3+
Kd6 33. Nd4 Re5 34. Nf3 Rc5 35. Nd4 Bg4 36. f3 Bd7 37. h3 Re5 38. Rf2 Re7
39. Rb1 Ke5 40. Rh1 h6 41. g3 Ref7 42. Rhh2 h5 43. g4 h4 44. Rh1 Rf4 45.
Rhf1 Re8 46. Rg1 Rg8 47. Rgf1 Rd8 48. Rd1 Rb8 49. Rb1 Re8 50. Re1 Rb8 51.
Rb1 Ra8 52. Ra1 Rd8 53. Rd1 Rh8 54. Rh1 Rhf8 55. Rhf1 Rg8 56. Rg1 Rb8 57.
Rb1 Rc8 58. Rc1 Ra8 59. Ra1 Raf8 60. Raf1 Rd8 61. Rd1 Re8 62. Re1 Rc8 63.
Rc1 Rg8 64. Rb1 Rgf8 65. Rbf1 Rd8 66. Rd1 Rc8 67. Rc1 Rb8 68. Rb1 Rbf8 69.
Rbf1 Re8 70. Re1 Rb8 71. Rb1 Ra8 72. Ra1 Rg8 73. Rg1 Re8 74. Re1 Rd8 75.
Rd1 Rg8 76. Rg1 Rb8 77. Rb1 Rc8 78. Rc1 Rcf8 79. Rcf1 Rb8 80. Rb1 Ra8 81.
Ra1 Rg8 82. Rg1 Rgf8 83. Rgf1 Rd8 84. Rd1 Rc8 85. Rc1 Rb8 86. Rb1 Ra8 87.
Ra1 Rh8 88. Rh1 Rg8 89. Rg1 Rgf8 90. Rgf1 Rb8 91. Rb1 Ra8 92. Ra1 Raf8 93.
Raf1 Rb8 94. Rb1 Re8 95. Re1 Ref8 96. Ref1 Rd8 97. Rd1 Rb8 98. Rb1 Rbf8 99.
Rbf1 Re8 100. Re1 Rd8 101. Rd1 Rdf8 102. Rdf1 Rg8 103. Rg1 Rgf8 104. Rgf1
Rb8 105. Rb1 Rbf8 106. Rbf1 Re8 107. Re1 Rd8 108. Rd1 Rb8 109. Rb1 Ra8 110.
Ra1 Rh8 111. Rh1 Rhf8 112. Rhf1 Rc8 113. Rc1 Rb8 114. Rb1 Rg8 115. Rg1 Re8
116. Re1 Rc8 117. Rc1 Ra8 118. Ra1 Rh8 119. Rh1 Rhf8 120. Rhf1 Rd8 121. Rd1
1/2-1/2
```

I have no idea what was going on with the following example. The repetition occurs 28 times, starting after White's 67th move.

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "?"]
[Site "Dos Hermanas"]
[Date "2004.03.08"]
[Round "9"]
[White "Garvin Mejia, Ricardo Luis"]
[Black "Arroyo, Roberto Carlos"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]

1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Qxd5 3. Nc3 Qa5 4. d4 Nf6 5. Bc4 Bf5 6. Ne2 e6 7. Ng3 Bg6
8. Bd2 c6 9. h4 h6 10. Nd5 Qd8 11. Nf4 Bh7 12. Qe2 Bxc2 13. Bc3 Bh7 14. d5
cxd5 15. Bxf6 gxf6 16. Nxd5 Be7 17. Nxe7 Qxe7 18. O-O O-O 19. Rfe1 Nc6 20.
Bb5 Nd4 21. Qg4+ Bg6 22. Qxd4 e5 23. Qg4 Kh8 24. Qe2 a6 25. Bd3 Rg8 26. Qe3
Kh7 27. Nf5 Bxf5 28. Bxf5+ Kg7 29. Rad1 Rad8 30. Rxd8 Qxd8 31. f4 exf4 32.
Qxf4 Qb6+ 33. Qf2 Qxf2+ 34. Kxf2 Rd8 35. Re2 Rd5 36. g4 Ra5 37. a3 Ra4 38.
Re7 b5 39. Ra7 a5 40. Be6 b4 41. Bxf7 Kf8 42. Bb3 bxa3 43. Bxa4 a2 44. Ra8+
Kg7 45. Ra7+ Kf8 46. Ra8+ Kg7 47. Ra7+ Kf8 48. Ra8+ Kg7 49. Ra7+ Kf8 50.
Ra8+ Kg7 51. Ra7+ Kf8 52. Ra8+ Kg7 53. Ra7+ Kf8 54. Ra8+ Kg7 55. Ra7+ Kf8
56. Ra8+ Kg7 57. Ra7+ Kf8 58. Ra8+ Kg7 59. Ra7+ Kf8 60. Ra8+ Kg7 61. Ra7+
Kf8 62. Ra8+ Kg7 63. Ra7+ Kf8 64. Ra8+ Kg7 65. Ra7+ Kf8 66. Rxa5 a1=Q 67.
Ra8+ Kg7 68. Ra7+ Kf8 69. Ra8+ Kg7 70. Ra7+ Kf8 71. Ra8+ Kg7 72. Ra7+ Kf8
73. Ra8+ Kg7 74. Ra7+ Kf8 75. Ra8+ Kg7 76. Ra7+ Kf8 77. Ra8+ Kg7 78. Ra7+
Kf8 79. Ra8+ Kg7 80. Ra7+ Kf8 81. Ra8+ Kg7 82. Ra7+ Kf8 83. Ra8+ Kg7 84.
Ra7+ Kf8 85. Ra8+ Kg7 86. Ra7+ Kf8 87. Ra8+ Kg7 88. Ra7+ Kf8 89. Ra8+ Kg7 
90. Ra7+ Kf8 91. Ra8+ Kg7 92. Ra7+ Kf8 93. Ra8+ Kg7 94. Ra7+ Kf8 95. Ra8+ 
Kg7 96. Ra7+ Kf8 97. Ra8+ Kg7 98. Ra7+ Kf8 99. Ra8+ Kg7 100. Ra7+ Kf8 101.
Ra8+ Kg7 102. Ra7+ Kf8 103. Ra8+ Kg7 104. Ra7+ Kf8 105. Ra8+ Kg7 106. Ra7+
Kf8 107. Ra8+ Kg7 108. Ra7+ Kf8 109. Ra8+ Kg7 110. Ra7+ Kf8 111. Ra8+ Kg7
112. Ra7+ Kf8 113. Ra8+ Kg7 114. Ra7+ Kf8 115. Ra8+ Kg7 116. Ra7+ Kf8 117.
Ra8+ Kg7 118. Ra7+ Kf8 119. Ra8+ Kg7 120. Ra7+ Kf8 121. Ra8+ 1/2-1/2
```

For completeness, here is the 131-move repetition but from the tags I presume this was played in an Under-10 tournament, so probably not of great significance:

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "GER-ch U10"]
[Site "Ueberlingen"]
[Date "2000.06.05"]
[Round "3"]
[White "Ugur, Ozgur"]
[Black "Cammann, Tim"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Nc3 Bb4 5. d3 Nd4 6. Be3 c5 7. O-O O-O 8.
a3 Bxc3 9. bxc3 Nxf3+ 10. Qxf3 d6 11. h3 Qa5 12. Qd1 Qxc3 13. Bd2 Qb2 14.
Ra2 Qb6 15. Qf3 Qd8 16. Qg3 Ne8 17. Bh6 Bd7 18. Be3 b5 19. Bb3 a5 20. c3 a4
21. Bc2 Qa5 22. Bd2 Rb8 23. Qe3 Be6 24. Rb2 Nf6 25. Rfb1 Bd7 26. c4 Qa6 27.
cxb5 Bxb5 28. Bc3 Rb7 29. Qd2 Rfb8 30. Qd1 h6 31. Bd2 d5 32. exd5 Nxd5 33.
Qg4 Bd7 34. Rxb7 Rxb7 35. Qd1 Rxb1 36. Qxb1 Qb5 37. Qe1 f6 38. Qe4 Qc6 39.
Bxa4 Qxa4 40. Qxd5+ Kh7 41. Qa2 Bb5 42. Be3 Qd1+ 43. Kh2 Qxd3 44. Bxc5 Qc4
45. Qxc4 Bxc4 46. Kg3 Kg8 47. Kg4 Kf7 48. Kh5 Be2+ 49. Kh4 g5+ 50. Kg3 h5
51. f3 f5 52. Be3 f4+ 53. Kf2 Bd3 54. Bd2 Kf6 55. Ke1 Kf5 56. Kf2 h4 57.
Ke1 e4 58. fxe4+ Bxe4 59. Kf2 g4 60. a4 g3+ 61. Kg1 Bd5 62. a5 Bc4 63. a6
Bxa6 64. Bxf4 Kxf4 65. Kh1 Bc8 66. Kg1 Bb7 67. Kh1 Bxg2+ 68. Kxg2 Ke3 69.
Kg1 Ke2 70. Kg2 Ke1 71. Kg1 Ke2 72. Kg2 Ke3 73. Kg1 Ke4 74. Kg2 Kf4 75. Kg1
Kf5 76. Kg2 Ke4 77. Kg1 Ke5 78. Kg2 Kf4 79. Kg1 Kf3 80. Kf1 Ke3 81. Kg1 Ke2
82. Kg2 Ke3 83. Kg1 Kf4 84. Kg2 Ke4 85. Kg1 Kd5 86. Kg2 Ke4 87. Kg1 Kd3 88.
Kh1 Kc3 89. Kg2 Kd2 90. Kh1 Kd3 91. Kg1 Kc4 92. Kg2 Kd5 93. Kh1 Ke6 94. Kg2
Kf7 95. Kf3 Kg6 96. Kg2 Kh5 97. Kf3 Kh6 98. Kg2 Kh7 99. Kg1 Kg8 100. Kh1
Kf8 101. Kg2 Ke8 102. Kg1 Kd8 103. Kh1 Kc8 104. Kg2 Kb8 105. Kg1 Ka8 106.
Kg2 Ka7 107. Kg1 Ka6 108. Kg2 Ka5 109. Kg1 Ka4 110. Kg2 Ka3 111. Kg1 Ka2
112. Kg2 Ka1 113. Kg1 Kb1 114. Kg2 Kc1 115. Kg1 Kb2 116. Kg2 Kb3 117. Kg1
Kb4 118. Kg2 Kb5 119. Kg1 Kb6 120. Kg2 Kb7 121. Kg1 Kb8 122. Kg2 Kc8 123.
Kg1 Kc7 124. Kf1 Kc6 125. Kg2 Kc5 126. Kg1 Kc4 127. Kg2 Kc3 128. Kg1 Kc2
129. Kg2 Kc1 130. Kg1 Kd1 131. Kh1 Kd2 132. Kg2 Kd3 133. Kh1 Kd4 134. Kg2
Kd5 135. Kg1 Kd6 136. Kg2 Kd7 137. Kg1 Kd8 138. Kg2 Ke8 139. Kg1 Ke7 140.
Kg2 Ke6 141. Kg1 Ke5 142. Kg2 Ke4 143. Kg1 Ke3 144. Kh1 Kf4 145. Kg2 Kg5
146. Kf3 Kh6 147. Kg2 Kh7 148. Kg1 Kg7 149. Kg2 Kf7 150. Kg1 Ke7 151. Kg2
Kd7 152. Kg1 Kc7 153. Kg2 Kb7 154. Kg1 Ka7 155. Kg2 Ka6 156. Kg1 Kb6 157.
Kg2 Kc6 158. Kg1 Kd6 159. Kg2 Ke6 160. Kg1 Kf6 161. Kg2 Kg6 162. Kg1 Kh5
163. Kg2 Kg5 164. Kg1 Kf5 165. Kg2 Ke5 166. Kg1 Kd5 167. Kg2 Kc5 168. Kg1
Kb5 169. Kg2 Ka5 170. Kg1 Ka4 171. Kg2 Ka3 172. Kg1 Ka2 173. Kg2 Kb2 174.
Kg1 Kc2 175. Kg2 Kd2 176. Kg1 Kd3 177. Kg2 Kd4 178. Kg1 Kd5 179. Kg2 Kd6
180. Kg1 Kd7 181. Kg2 Kd8 182. Kf1 Ke8 183. Kg1 Kf8 184. Kg2 Kg8 185. Kg1
Kh8 186. Kg2 Kh7 187. Kg1 Kh6 188. Kg2 Kh5 189. Kg1 Kg5 190. Kg2 Kf5 191.
Kg1 Ke5 192. Kg2 Kd5 193. Kg1 Kc6 194. Kg2 Kb5 195. Kg1 Kb4 196. Kg2 Kc4
197. Kg1 Kd3 198. Kg2 Ke4 199. Kg1 Ke5 200. Kg2 Kf6 201. Kf1 Kf7 202. Kg1
Kg7 203. Kg2 Kf6 204. Kg1 Ke7 205. Kg2 Kd7 206. Kf3 Kc6 207. Ke2 Kc5 208.
Kf1 Kc4 209. Kg2 Kb4 210. Kg1 Kb5 211. Kg2 Kc6 212. Kg1 Kd7 213. Kg2 Ke7
214. Kg1 Kd6 215. Kg2 Kc7 216. Kg1 Kb6 217. Kg2 Ka5 218. Kg1 Ka6 219. Kg2
Ka7 220. Kg1 Ka8 221. Kg2 Kb8 222. Kg1 Kc8 223. Kg2 Kd8 224. Kg1 Ke8 225.
Kg2 Kf8 226. Kg1 Kg8 227. Kg2 Kh7 228. Kg1 Kg6 229. Kg2 Kf5 230. Kg1 Ke6
231. Kg2 Kd6 232. Kg1 Kc7 233. Kg2 Kd8 234. Kg1 Ke7 235. Kg2 Kf7 236. Kg1
Ke6 237. Kg2 Kd5 238. Kg1 Kc4 239. Kg2 Kb3 240. Kg1 Kc4 241. Kg2 Kc3 242.
Kg1 Kb4 243. Kg2 Ka5 244. Kg1 Kb6 245. Kh1 Kc7 246. Kg1 Kd8 247. Kh1 Ke8
248. Kg1 Kd7 249. Kg2 Kc6 250. Kg1 Kb6 251. Kf1 Kc5 252. Kg2 Kd5 253. Kg1
Kd4 254. Kg2 Kd5 255. Kg1 Ke6 256. Kg2 Kf7 257. Kg1 Kf6 258. Kg2 Kf5 259.
Kg1 Ke5 260. Kg2 Kd5 261. Kg1 Kc4 262. Kf1 Kd5 263. Kg2 Kc6 264. Kg1 Kb5
265. Kg2 Kb4 266. Kg1 Kc5 267. Kg2 Kd6 268. Kg1 Ke5 269. Kg2 Kd5 270. Kg1
Kc4 271. Kg2 Kc3 272. Kg1 Kb3 273. Kg2 Kc4 274. Kg1 Kd3 275. Kh1 Ke4 276.
Kg2 Ke5 277. Kg1 Ke6 278. Kg2 Kf6 279. Kg1 Kg7 1/2-1/2
```

Comment: Are we sure the game (Tisma-Krasteva) was finished because a player claimed a threefold repetition ? Since either of the players could have claimed a threefold earlier (for instance, after Black 82nd move) and didn't, could it be that the game ended on a draw offer or on a 50-moves claim ?

Answer (score 2):

I would say 50 moves (possibly 49).

Three-fold repetition requires the game to return same position 3 times.  This obviously can't happen if there are any captures or pawn moves, so therefore as long as the 3-fold repetition is possible so is the 50-move rule - which provides a hard upper limit.

Comment: Keep in mind that claiming a draw under the 50-move rule is not mandatory, so the game could continue if none of the players make a claim. There is however a newer 75-move rule which results in a draw whether the players want it or not.

Comment: @itub yeah, it's not mandatory, but then again neither is claiming a draw under 3-fold repetition.

Comment: But note that under the newest FIDE laws, 75-move and fivefold repetition ARE mandatory draws - if an arbiter observes it, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I found this what is perhaps the strangest repetition ever in [Tim Krabbe's Diary #26.](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/diary_2.htm) I shall quote it in full for context.

"Last night on ICC, using my alias for the command obs * -c (which will get you to see the highest rated non-computer game), I chanced upon a 3 5 game between grandmasters Grandma (2938) and KingLoek (2929). After 39 moves, the position in the diagram was reached. There followed: 39...Rb5+ 40.Kc2 Rc5 41.Kb3 Rb5+ 42.Kc2 Rc5 43.Kb3 Rb5+ ICC does spot repetitions, but will only declare the game a draw if one of the players clicks 'draw'. Here, neither did. The game continued, watched by at least 60 people, including a few grandmasters:"

```
[FEN "8/p2R2pp/5k2/2rn1p2/2N5/PK3PP1/7P/8 b - - 0 1"]

1... Rb5+ 2. Kc2 Rc5 3. Kb3 Rb5+ 4. Kc2 Rc5 5. Kb3 Rb5+ 6. Kc2 Rc5 7. Kb3 Rb5+ 8. Kc2 Rc5 9. Kb3 Rb5+ 10. Kc2 Rc5 11. Kb3 Rb5+ 12. Kc2 Rc5 13. Kb3 Rb5+ 14. Kc2 Rc5 15. Kb3 Rb5+ 16. Kc2 Rc5 17. Kb3 Rb5+ 18. Kc2 Rc5 19. Kb3 Rb5+ 20. Kc2 Rc5 21. Kb3 Rb5+ 22. Kc2 Rc5 23. Kb3 Rb5+ 24. Kc2 Rc5 25. Kb3 Rb5+ 26. Kc2 Rc5 27. Kb3 Rb5+ 28. Kc2 Rc5 29. Kb3 Rb5+ 30. Kc2 Rc5 31. Kb3 Rb5+ 32. Kc2 Rc5 33. Kb3 Rb5+ 34. Kc2 Rc5 35. Kb3 Rb5+ 36. Kc2 Rc5 37. Kb3 Rb5+ 38. Kc2 Rc5 39. Kb3 Rb5+ 40. Kc2 Rc5 41. Kb3 Rb5+ 42. Kc2 Rc5 43. Kb3 Rb5+ 44. Kc2 Rc5 45. Kb3 Rb5+ 46. Kc2 Rc5 47. Kb3 Rb5+ 48. Kc2 Rc5 49. Kb3 Rb5+ 50. Kc2 Rc5 51. Kb3 Rb5+ 52. Kc2 Rc5 53. Kb3 Rb5+ 54. Kc2 Rc5 55. Kb3 Rb5+ 56. Kc2 Rc5 57. Kb3 Rb5+ 58. Kc2 Rc5 59. Kb3 Rb5+ 60. Kc2 Rc5 61. Kb3 Rb5+ 62. Kc2 Rc5 63. Kb3 Rb5+ 64. Kc2 Rc5 65. Kb3 Rb5+ 66. Kc2 Rc5 67. Kb3 Rb5+ 68. Kc2 Rc5 69. Kb3 Rb5+ 70. Kc2 Rc5 71. Kb3 Rb5+ 72. Kc2 Rc5 73. Kb3 Rb5+ 74. Kc2 Rc5 75. Kb3 Rb5+ 76. Kc2 Rc5 77. Kb3 Rb5+ 78. Kc2 Rc5 79. Kb3 Rb5+ 80. Kc2 Rc5 81. Kb3 Rb5+ 82. Kc2 Rc5 83. Kb3 Rb5+ 84. Kc2 Rc5 85. Kb3 Rb5+ 86. Kc2 Rc5 87. Kb3 Rb5+ 88. Kc2 Rc5 89. Kb3 Rb5+ 90. Kc2 Rc5 91. Kb3 Rb5+ 92. Kc2 Rc5 93. Kb3 Rb5+ 94. Kc2 Rc5 95. Kb3 Rb5+ 96. Kc2 Rc5 97. Kb3 Rb5+ 98. Kc2 Rc5 99. Kb3 Rb5+ 100. Kc2 Rc5 101. Kb3 Rb5+ 102. Kc2 Rc5 103. Kb3 Rb5+ 104. Kc2 Rc5 105. Kb3 Rb5+ 106. Kc2 Rc5 107. Kb3 Rb5+ 108. Kc2 Rc5 109. Kb3 Rb5+ 110. Kc2 Rc5 111. Kb3 Rb5+ 1/2-1/2
```

"44.Kc2 Rc5 45.Kb3 Rb5+ 46.Kc2 Rc5 47.Kb3 Rb5+ 48.Kc2 Rc5 49.Kb3 Rb5+ 50.Kc2 Rc5 51.Kb3 Rb5+ 52.Kc2 Rc5 53.Kb3 Rb5+ 54.Kc2 Rc5 55.Kb3 Rb5+ 56.Kc2 Rc5 57.Kb3 Rb5+ 58.Kc2 Rc5 59.Kb3 Rb5+ 60.Kc2 Rc5 61.Kb3 Rb5+ 62.Kc2 Rc5 63.Kb3 Rb5+ 64.Kc2 Rc5 65.Kb3 Rb5+ 66.Kc2 Rc5 67.Kb3 Rb5+ 68.Kc2 Rc5 69.Kb3 Rb5+ 70.Kc2 Rc5 71.Kb3 Rb5+ 72.Kc2 Rc5 73.Kb3 Rb5+ 74.Kc2 Rc5 75.Kb3 Rb5+ 76.Kc2 Rc5 77.Kb3 Rb5+ 78.Kc2 Rc5 79.Kb3 Rb5+ 80.Kc2 Rc5 81.Kb3 Rb5+ 82.Kc2 Rc5 83.Kb3 Rb5+ 84.Kc2 Rc5 85.Kb3 Rb5+ 86.Kc2 Rc5 87.Kb3 Rb5+ 88. Kc2 Rc5 89.Kb3 Rb5+ 90.Kc2 Rc5 91.Kb3 Rb5+ 92.Kc2 Rc5 93.Kb3 Rb5+ 94.Kc2 Rc5 95.Kb3 Rb5+ 96.Kc2 Rc5 97.Kb3 Rb5+ 98.Kc2 Rc5 99.Kb3 Rb5+ 100.Kc2 Rc5 101.Kb3 Rb5+ 102.Kc2 Rc5 103.Kb3 Rb5+ 104.Kc2 Rc5 105. Kb3 Rb5+ 106.Kc2 Rc5 107.Kb3 Rb5+ 108.Kc2 Rc5 109.Kb3 Rb5+ 110.Kc2 Rc5 111.Kb3 Rb5+ 112.Kc2 Rc5 113.Kb3 Rb5+ 114.Kc2 Rc5 115.Kb3 Rb5+ 116.Kc2 Rc5 117.Kb3 Rb5+ 118.Kc2 Rc5 119.Kb3 Rb5+ 120.Kc2 Rc5 121. Kb3 Rb5+ 122.Kc2 Rc5 123.Kb3 Rb5+ 124.Kc2 Rc5 125.Kb3 Rb5+ 126.Kc2 Rc5 127.Kb3 Rb5+ 128.Kc2 Rc5 129.Kb3 Rb5+ 130.Kc2 Rc5 131.Kb3 Rb5+ 132.Kc2 Rc5 133.Kb3 Rb5+ 134.Kc2 Rc5 135.Kb3 Rb5+ 136.Kc2 Rc5 137. Kb3 Rb5+ 138.Kc2 Rc5 139.Kb3 Rb5+ 140.Kc2 Rc5 141.Kb3 Rb5+ 142.Kc2 Rc5 143.Kb3 Rb5+ 144.Kc2 Rc5 145.Kb3 Rb5+ 146.Kc2 Rc5 147.Kb3 Rb5+ 148.Kc2 Rc5 149.Kb3 Rb5+ and here the text appeared: 'Game drawn by repetition 1/2-1/2'"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the theoretical maximum is 75 moves. This is based on the Article 9.6.2 of the FIDE Laws of Chess, which defines
"The game is drawn if any series of at least 75 moves have been made by each player without the movement of any pawn and without any capture."

This is perhaps best explained with an example. Suppose the second occurrence of the position happens 50 moves after the first occurrence, and the third occurrence happens 26 moves after the second occurrence. This means that the player will claim a draw 76 moves after the first occurrence, and the arbiter will evaluate and declare a draw already in the previous move by the 75 moves rule. The 76.th. move is in effect not a part of the game, because it already ended with a draw. This would only happen if the arbiter was not already attentive to declare the draw on the previous move, which can happen because arbiters have many duties during a tournament, and will not always check each game for this rule.